# regex to remove /page/1

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace /some/string/page/45 to /some/string only. This is what I am using for it:

```
preg_replace('~((?<=\?)page/\d+&?|&page/\d+)~i', '', $this->__tmp)
```

but its not working for me. I tried online tools to generate regex I need but it's too hard for me.. I need to replace /page/(any number)

also I have generated this one:

```
preg_replace('~(page/\d+)~i', '', $this->__tmp);
```

and it looks works fine, but I don't know if its correct.

Comment: Do you just want to remove everything after the last `/`?

Comment: for example I have `some/string/more/options/page/2` and I need to get only `some/string/more/options`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```php
<?php

$str = 'asd/qwe/page/123';

$result = preg_replace('(/page/\d+)', '', $str);

var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
string(8) "asd/qwe"
```

If you want delete first and end slash (not required first and last slashes, supported many slashes in start of string and in end of string):

```php
<?php

$str = '////asd/qwe/page/123////';

$result = preg_replace('~^(/)*(.*)(/page/\d+)(/)*~', '$2', $str);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: thanks, thats worked as well. Is there any option to extend it to remove first and last slashes from string? not necessary for me, but maybe someone else will find it as answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using preg_match over preg_replace you could do something like this:

```
<?php

$regex = "/(?!^\/).*(?=\/page)/";
$regStr = "/some/string/page/45";

preg_match($regex, $regStr, $results);

print_r($results);

?>
```

And the result will be:

```
Array ( [0] => some/string )
```

Hope this helps!